# How to fix Sublime text highlighting for react-tutorial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext3

I recently started the [official reactjs tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) and noticed that the sublime text highlighting is completely screwed.

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: You may try JS or JSX (Babel) highliter in CudaText editor app, should be correct here.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Install `babel` with the package control package, if you don't have it, get it [here](https://packagecontrol.io/).

Open the package control, select install package, type babel, select it and press enter.

**Setting as the default syntax**

To set it as the default syntax for a particular extension:

- Open a file with that extension, Select View from the menu, Then
  Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> Babel ->
  JavaScript (Babel). Repeat this for each extension (e.g.: .js and
  .jsx).

**Setting a Color Scheme**

Babel comes bundled with Next and Monokai from Benvie/JavaScriptNext.tmLanguage. Select one from Preferences -> Color Scheme -> Babel

Comment: You, Sir, saved my sanity!

Comment: Easy to follow instructions.

Comment: after installing bablel; you could also do command + shift + p then type in babel, "Set Syntax: Javascript (Babel)" should show up, hit enter, then it should work

Answer (score 4):

- Follow [this link](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) to install the package manager for sublime text
- Now to open the command palette, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (Win, Linux) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (OS X). From the search results select **Package Control: Install Package**. Now find and select packages Babel and Babel Snippets.
- Now to enable proper syntax highlighting for your JSX code, open your .js/.jsx file, select View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> Babel -> JavaScript (Babel).

Answer (score 2):

Installing the following sublime package should fix those problems:

https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime

Answer (score 2):

Install `babel` via the package control. It'll fix the syntax highlighting and adds few more features.

check https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel